# Pandas, how to combine multiple columns into an array column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to put a combined column as the concat of all values of the row.

Source:

```
pd.DataFrame(data={
    'a' : [1,2,3],
    'b' : [2,3,4]
})
```

Target:

```
pd.DataFrame(data={
    'a' : [1,2,3],
    'b' : [2,3,4],
    'combine' : [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]
})
```

Current solution:

```
test['combine'] = test[['a','b']].apply(lambda x: pd.Series([x.values]), axis=1)
```

Issues:
I actually have many columns, it seems taking too long to run. Is it a better way.

Comment: This seems overly simple... `df['combine'] = df.values.tolist()`

Comment: Don't use an `apply` where you can avoid it.

Comment: One last thing to note is that such columns are essentially useless. Don't keep columns in this format if you're going to do more than just display.

Answer (score 26):

```
df

   a  b
0  1  2
1  2  3
2  3  4
```

If you want to add a column of lists as a single column, you'll need to call the `.values` attribute, convert it to a nested list, and assign it back -

```
df['combine'] = df.values.tolist()
# or,
df['combine'] = df[['a', 'b']].values.tolist()
```

```
df
   a  b combine
0  1  2  [1, 2]
1  2  3  [2, 3]
2  3  4  [3, 4]
```

Note that just assigning the `.values` result directly does not work, as `pandas` *special cases* numpy arrays, leading to undesirable outcomes,

```
df['combine'] = df[['a', 'b']].values

ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1
```

---

A couple of notes -

- try not to use `apply`/`transform` as much as possible. It is only a convenience function meant to hide the application of a loop, and is slow, offering no performance/vectorization benefits whatosever
- keeping columns of `objects offers no performance gains as far as pandas is concerned, so unless the goal is to display data, try to avoid it.

Comment: is there a way by which one can merge the columns into a numpy array. I mean here `type` of `df['combine'].iloc[0]` would be `list`, can one make sure it is `numpy.ndarray` while merging itself?